# Problem with extracting tar.gz files

Tags: 13.10, archive, extract

I was downloading something today and when I tried to extract it, a window pop out saying :

```
An error ocurred while extracting files. Error setting owner: operation not permitted
```

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 saucy salamander.

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This may be an [Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file-roller/+bug/1238266) in File Roller (the default archiver installed in Ubuntu).

To work around this, you can use the Terminal. Use the following commands :

```
cd [DIRECTORY]
tar -xvzf [ARCHIVE NAME]
```

**  Right click on the file and select `Properties`. Copy the content under `Location`. Replace the `[DIRECTORY]` by it. Do the same and Copy the content under `Name` . Replace `[ARCHIVE NAME]` with it.

The first command changes your current working directory to the directory containing the archive. The second command invokes the `tar` utility to extract the file.

Comment: This is what the terminal gave me: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: If there is a space in between the file name, you must enclose it in quotes, for instance: `tar -xvzf "My Archive.tar.gz"`.